# Как правильно добавить объект в словарь?

Tags: python, python-3.x, словари, структуры-данных, dict

Есть такой исходный словарь:

```
{
  'бублик': {
    '617401283': {
      {
          'time': 1617639045.4909863,
          'damage': 1000
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Нужно в '617401283' добавить еще один объект, чтобы на выходе было:

```
{
  'бублик': {
    '617401283': {
      {
          'time': 1617639045.4909863,
          'damage': 1000
      },
      {
          'time': 16176392.4909863,
          'damage': 499
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Я пробовал метод `.update()` но он перезаписывает входные данные, а`.append` и `+=` не работают с типом `dict`. Вопрос: как правильно добавить такую запись к существующему словарю?

Comment: судя по структуре в `617401283` находится такой тип данных как множество, а это значит что нужно использовать `add`. `my_dict['бублик'].add({'time': 1, 'damage: 1'})`

Comment: Судя по структуре, это вообще непонятно что, но явно не питоновский словарь.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Для "правильного добавления в словарь объекта" вам нужен корректный словарь, например такой:

```
my_dict = {
  'бублик': {
    '617401283': [
      {
          'time': 1617639045.4909863,
          'damage': 1000
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

потом в список, который является значением словаря, можно добавить запись:

```
new_data = {'time': 16176392.4909863, 'damage': 499}
my_dict['бублик']['617401283'].append(new_data)
```

в итоге:

```
{'бублик': 
    {'617401283': [
        {'time': 1617639045.4909863, 'damage': 1000}, 
        {'time': 16176392.4909863, 'damage': 499}
    ]}
}
```

PS словарь - структура вида "ключ: значение", нельзя без ключа добавить в словарь несколько других словарей... и в set (если "617401283" - set) нельзя пометить словари: нужны хешируемые типы данных...